# How to enforce SLF4J usage in Java code with ArchUnit

Tags: java, junit, archunit

I wanna use [ArchUnit](https://www.archunit.org/) to enforce usage only [SLF4J logging framework](http://www.slf4j.org/) and avoid simple `System.out` calls. Also I would like to avoid any other logging frameworks for using. How can I implement the such check?

Currently I write this test

```
class EnforceSlf4JLoggingTest {

    private final JavaClasses importedClasses = new ClassFileImporter()
            .withImportOption(new ImportOption.DoNotIncludeTests())
            .importPackages("... my packages ...");

    @Test
    public void classesShouldNotUseJavaUtilLogging() {
        NO_CLASSES_SHOULD_USE_JAVA_UTIL_LOGGING.check(importedClasses);
    }

    @Test
    public void classesShouldNotUseSystemOutLogging() {
        noClasses()
                .should()
                .dependOnClassesThat()
                .belongToAnyOf(java.lang.System.class)
                .because("use SLF4J instead")
                .check(importedClasses);
    }
}
```

but it doesn't actually enforce SLF4J usage but only restrict `java.unit.logging` usage and prevent of having dependency to `java.lang.System` class (where actually `System.out` constant is located).

**Whether is more elegant solution of my case?**

Comment: " I would like to avoid any other logging frameworks" SLF4J is not a logging framework. It's just a standardized API for logging frameworks. You still need an implementation based on an actualy logging framework such as JUL, Log4J or Logback...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no a simple way to avoid usage any other loggig systems beside of SLF4J but it's possible to use this ArchUnit check template

```
ArchRuleDefinition.noClasses()
  .should().dependOnClassesThat()
  .resideInAnyPackage(
    "java.util.logging..", 
    "org.apache.logging.."
  ).as("Please only depend on SLF4J as a logging framework");
```

In the section `resideInAnyPackage` should be specified packages of different logging systems have to be avoided.

Also, rule

```
com.tngtech.archunit.library.GeneralCodingRules.NO_CLASSES_SHOULD_ACCESS_STANDARD_STREAMS
```

has to be used to check absents any plain `System.out`, `System.err` and `printStackTrace` calls in code.